# Dropbox iOS Sync API add observer not called appropriately

Tags: ios, dropbox, dropbox-api

The following observer does not gets called if a file is deleted or added inside the folder at 'path':

```
- (BOOL)addObserver:(id)observer forPath:(DBPath *)path block:(DBObserver)block;
```

What is the point of the method then, when is it called?

The following does get called if any file is deleted/added/modified inside the folder at 'path'

```
- (BOOL)addObserver:(id)observer forPathAndChildren:(DBPath *)path block:(DBObserver)block;
```

I want to be able to differentiate when a file contained inside a folder was modifies versus when file(s) were added/deleted inside the folder at 'path'.

Following is the code I'm using to register for observer:

```
#define DATA_FOLDER_NAME @"Portfolio_Data"
DBFilesystem* filesystem = [DBFilesystem sharedFilesystem];
DBPath *portfolioFilesPath = [[DBPath root] childPath:DATA_FOLDER_NAME];

    [filesystem addObserver:self forPath:portfolioFilesPath block:^{

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self getPortfoliosData];
        });
    }];
```

Comment: Show the actual code where you setup the observer.

Answer (score 0):

A few things.

1. `addObserver:forPath:block:` is used to track changes just to the file at the path.
2. `addObserver:forPathAndChildren:block:` is used to track changes to the folder at the path as well as any direct children inside the file at path (but not children of those children).
3. To do what you want takes a bit more work. To listen for changes to individual files you need to create a `DBFile` for each and add an observer to the file. This observer will be called when the file is changed or deleted. Then you need to use the `addObserver:forPathAndChildren:block:` (or `addObserver:forPathAndDescendants:block:`) to listen for general changes within the folder. The big issue is when your block is called, you only know "something" changed. You need to scan the folder looking for new files. You can ignore existing or deleted files since the observers you setup for each will be called when the file is changed or deleted.

This is one major drawback over the Dropbox Sync API over iCloud API. iCloud tells you what file was added in the folder, Dropbox does not.

Comment: The documentation says that addObserver:forPath:block: notified any time the file or folder at path changes so what kind of change at folder are we talking about then ?

I understand these differences and that is what I have done.

Comment: Folder changes could include renaming the folder and deleting the folder but I don't believe it includes changes to the contents of the folder.

Comment: The API does act weird when you yourself make changes and observer gets called e.g. it can give an exception on a newly created file that it cannot 'open a folder' when its not even a folder. I just prevent this type of issue by not calling my sync method when its my own changes triggering it

Comment: it seems you are suggesting in point #3 that addObserver:forPathAndChildren:block: will be called when contents of a folder changed but it does not get called when for example a new file is added to the folder

Comment: @2cupsOfTech I'm not suggesting that. `addObserver:forPathAndChildren:block:` is called when new files are added as well as when files are changed/deleted.

Comment: so pointing to my original question when there are changes (e.g. new file added) inside a specific folder how do I get notification for that?

Comment: that was my point these methods don't get called if you for example create copy of an existing file within a folder